# Smoother animation ImageSwitcher

Tags: android, animation, smoothing, imageswitcher

I'm using fade_in and fade_out animations avaible android.R.anim.fade_in(fade_out). Basically I can change duration of animation but no matter if it's 0,5 or 2 seconds animation is still not smooth. Is there any way to make a fade in/out animation smoother? Thanks a lot!

*Code:*

```
imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageswitcher);

    slide_in_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);
    slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);

    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);
```

*XML fade_out:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things you can do to improve the Animation. First, enable hardware acceleration in your Android Manfiest, by adding the application attribute:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Next, try some different *interpolator*s. You may find `@android:anim/linear` to be smoother.

Finally, if this does not work, you can always do this programmatically use [Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) (you can use [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com) for older API versions).

Comment: Wow, it works perfect! Should I set hardwareAcceleration="false" after animation right?

Comment: @Matwosk you can leave the setting in your manifest. If you wish, there is a way to  programmatically disable hardware acceleration, but for most cases it's fine to leave it on.

Comment: After adding this to my manifest i lost the background image on one activity. Any idea why?

Comment: Found it there are limitations to image sizes with hardware acceleration

Comment: @Msmit1993 yes, Bitmaps can only be at most the size of the device screen.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is also minimizing my app's background image's file size.